Keras Tuner for a (stacked) LSTM model?
I have a question about how to correctly setup a Keras Tuner model for a stacked LSTM model.
What I have tried is the normal tutorial with a loop and the hp.Int() function to define the size of each LSTM layer like this:
for i in range(hp.Int('num_lstm_layers', min_value=1, max_value=4)):
   lstm_units_i = hp.Int('units_' + str(i), min_value=2**6, max_value=2**9, step=2**5) 
   lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(lstm_units_i, return_sequences=True), name=f'lstm_{i}')(lstm)

However, with this configuration the second and third layer could have more units compared to the first layer (and so on) - this is not something we would want, is it? We would want the layers to get smaller and force the model to learn on less data? The reason i ask is, because the 'best' model afterwards was one, where the second layer was double of the first layer for example, and I dont know if this is 'correct' for LSMTs?
I also have created a for loop, whit the condition that the next layer can only be as deep as the layer beforehand like this:
for i in range(hp.Int('num_lstm_layers', min_value=1, max_value=4)):

        if lstm_units_prev is not None:
            lstm_units_i = hp.Int('units_' + str(i), min_value=2**6, max_value=lstm_units_prev, step=2**5)
        else:
            lstm_units_i = hp.Int('units_' + str(i), min_value=2**6, max_value=2**9, step=2**5)
            
        lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(lstm_units_i, return_sequences=True))(lstm)
        lstm_units_prev = lstm_units_i

Would this be the preferred way, or does it not matter?
Thanks,
Barry
